# How should I input command line arguments into this dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm expanding a script of mine that essentially pulls JSON data from a weather API.

I've decided to use argparse to accept arguments.

```
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", help="zipcode")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--api", help="API")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm making a request to pull the data; like this:

```
params = { 'zip': "''\,us", 'APPID': '' }
```

How should I approach propagating that input into the string in order to execute the request?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
params = {'zip': args.zip + ',us', 'APPID': args.api}
```

Edit:

I realize you didn't specify type in your arguments:

```
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", type=str, help="zipcode")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--api", type=str, help="API")
```

Otherwise the params will have to be:

```
params = {'zip': str(args.zip) + ',us', 'APPID': str(args.api)}
```